# Session-based Server Side Data Setting and Retrieval

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web-services, model-view-controller

I have a theoretical question about how to approach a current project. It is a fairly simple matching quiz using JS + PHP. I am simply taking care of business logic on the server (answer checking, score updating) such as to roughly follow MVC conventions.

My current setup:

- HTML + JS page to allow the user to drag and drop answers onto questions. On a successful drop, the question + answer combo is sent to the following:
- A server-side PHP page to check the answer correctness based on an XML file. I return a few pieces of data in some XML client, such as true/false and number of attempts at a certain question. **In addition, if the answer is correct, I increment a Session Variable on the server to keep track of the user's score.**

My question revolves around best practices for setting the above mentioned session variable for tracking the score. I understand that a more persistent setup is most likely preferable, in case of computer shut-off, accidental browser closing, etc...but strictly based on this setup -

1. Is this a secure method for storing a score for a final insertion into the database?
2. I eventually will have to pull the score down from the server at the end of the game (or even mid game, for that matter), as well. Should I create a simple 'getter' PHP page to pull the score down, and just access the session variable and send it to the client?
3. Currently, the user actually has access to the php server-side page becuase it resides in the same folder as the actual quiz. This is moooost likely a no-no - but what is the common practice for hiding this server-only file from the user's prying eyes (without having to use authentication)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this a secure method for storing a score for a final insertion into the database?

It is secure. But I don't see a why you wouldn't update the scores in the database as they are changed. This way it *will* be persistent.

> I eventually will have to pull the score down from the server at the end of the game (or even mid game, for that matter), as well. Should I create a simple 'getter' PHP page to pull the score down, and just access the session variable and send it to the client?

Sounds like a plan.

> Currently, the user actually has access to the php server-side page becuase it resides in the same folder as the actual quiz. This is moooost likely a no-no - but what is the common practice for hiding this server-only file from the user's prying eyes (without having to use authentication)?

As long as the files are .php files and are parsed by the webserver the user can only do requests to the files and that's it (if I understood the question correct that is).

Comment: Thanks! Regarding the last question - if they access the .php page it actually spits out XML as if my Javascript page had called it and it was returning an answer. It even increments the 'attempts' and variable simply because the PHP page had been called. Seems odd to me... :)

Comment: @SpencerAllenGardner I don't think there is a way to prevent users from going to the link directly.

Answer (score 0):

check out this. I hope this will help you

http://www.linuxforu.com/2009/01/server-side-sessions/